# How do I delete Address book entry

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following address list:

```
  lst=  ['Andrea', '21', 'andrea@hotmail.com', 'Brenda', '1211', 'brenda@yahoo.co.uk']
```

That I turned into a Dictionary using the following code that is containing my delete command (not working):

```
name=str(input("Name:"))
lst = sum(lst, [])
names= lst[::3]
numbers= lst[1::3]
emails = lst[2::3]
dct = {name: (number,email) for name, number, email in zip(names, numbers, emails)}
if name in dct:
    del dct[name]
    print("Deleted!")
else:
    print("Doesn´t exist!")
```

And what I want it to do is to delete the contact info of the name you inserted and turn it back again into a list so I could update the real list "books", per example if you want to delete Brenda and turned the dictionary back to a list of lists:

```
lst = [['Andrea', '21', 'andrea@hotmail.com']]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `lst` the same as `book`?

Comment: With `lst = book` instead of `lst = sum(lst, [])`, this code works. What is the problem?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, it works, but Phyti also wants to have it back as a list.

Comment: @scope - That's just to show that Brenda was removed. It specifically says that the code "containing [the] delete command" is "not working."

Comment: *per example if you want to delete Brenda and turned the dictionary back to a list of lists:* - how do you turn it *"back"* to a list of lists, when it doesn't start out as a list of lists? Is the input example showing the wrong data and so the dictionary doesn't build properly, and can't delete?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I assume the `lst = sum(lst, [])` part is flattening a 2D `lst` (that isn't shown) into `books` (which is the "real" one somehow; I'm not clear on it).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes lst is the same as books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
book = ['Andrea', '21', 'andrea@hotmail.com', 'Brenda', '1211', 'brenda@yahoo.co.uk']
input_name = str(raw_input("Name:"))
updatedBook = [[name, number, email] for name, number, email in zip(book[::3], book[1::3], book[2::3]) if name != input_name]
print updatedBook
```

Comment: Do you really have to build an entirely new object? There's no explanation of what you're doing, either.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can we do it like this  : >>> list(reduce(lambda x, y, z: x + y + z, book.items()))    ?

Comment: @Phyti - I don't know, but you're using Python 3, so `reduce` would be an import from `functools`, because it's kind of deprecated. Also, don't use `reduce`, because it's kind of deprecated.

Comment: Could be solved with this for sure if you are allowed or want to work with dict´s

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve in line 2, but when `list` should be the same as `book` your code almost does what you want it to do.

Assuming that certain values (numbers or email addresses) *might* be not distinct values, the best way is rebuilding the list of addresses.

This can be done with some code like:

```
book = []
for key, value in list:
    book.append(key)
    book.extend(list(value))
```

However please keep in mind that this code does *not* guarantee that the order of the addresses in book are the same as before (The order of the values of a single entry are kept, of course).

---

I just reread your question and saw that you expect a list of lists, then of course you can use this:

```
book = [[key, value[0], value[1]] for key, value in list]
```

Comment: Why does the possible uniqueness of the values necessitate building an entirely new object?

Comment: I'm no python expert, but since we are talking about lists objects, which are python builtin primitives, I guess creating a new list is far less expensive than removing list elements from within the list. In the latter case all elements after the inserted elements have to be shifted in order to make place for the new elements. However one might has to run tests to check which is faster.